# How loud would a sound have to be for it to travel the distance of Pittsburgh, Pennsylvania to New York, NY?

Tags: acoustics, estimation, distance

I'm just wondering if it's possible, more than anything. But if it is, how many decibels would the sound have to be to travel that far of a distance?

Comment: For reference you should at least edit in relevant information like the actual distance between these places.

Comment: Please also add how good your hearing is. Any sound wave will reach any place in the atmosphere, only its amplitude may be extremely small.

Comment: Philly to Pitt is about 300 miles, so it's probably 320 mi range @StephenG

Answer (score 3):

Probably.

An atomic bomb, for instance, could produce a sound that would travel this far on a good day (or a bad day, depending on how one feels about pittsburgh). We'll just consider frequencies in the very lowest range of human hearing (~20 Hz), because the lowest frequencies carry the farthest. We can't expect acoustic attenuation to be much lower than $10^{-3}$ decibels per 100 meters in the best of conditions [[1](http://www.mne.psu.edu/lamancusa/me458/10_osp.pdf)]. Its about 510 km from new york city to pittsburgh. That means that if you had a long tube (a soundproof one at that) from pittsburgh to new york and you listened on one end, total attenuation due to air absorbing the sound would be about a half a decibel at the very lowest. Under these conditions, you could probably even hear someone talking into the other end of the tube.

However, if you don't have such a tube, you'll have to contend with sounds getting quieter because they spread out as they travel (a phenomenon called 'spherical divergence'). As a rule of thumb, this adds 6 decibels of attenuation for every doubling of the length between the sound and the listener. The sound of a nuclear test peaked at 210 decibels at a distance of 250 ft [[2](https://www.dallasobserver.com/music/loud-noises-the-very-short-list-of-things-that-are-actually-louder-than-dallas-mavericks-fans-7069258)]. To get to 510 km from 250 feet we have to double the length about 13 times [[3](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log+base+2+of+(510+km%2F250+ft)], so the sound attenuates by about 80 decibels. After this attenuation the sound would be about 130 dB, which is still *really* loud. However, this only applies to sounds in the lowest range of human hearing; a sound this loud at a frequency of 260 Hz (near middle C on a piano), for instance, would be attenuated by something on the order of 50 Hz, and so would reach new york at around 30 dB, about as loud as a whisper. It is actually more likely that one would *feel* the blast from this far away, rather than hear it, and it might lead to broken windows, etc.